# How to show empty text in list fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using Google Place API to find nearest places. I am displaying map and list on two tabs. I have made two fragments. In one i am showing map and in second one i am using list. I have used an editext box on actionbar. When i am running my app it is crashing and giving nullpointer exception at setListAdapter.

It is my ListFragment file

```
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.aquib.android.place.Place;
import com.aquib.android.place.PlaceAdapter;
import com.aquib.android.place.R;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by dell on 2/9/2015.
 */
public class ListItemFragment extends ListFragment{

    private PlaceAdapter adapter;
    List<Place> placeList;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, null);
        TextView emptyTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
        emptyTextView.setTextSize(10);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        adapter = new PlaceAdapter(getActivity(), placeList);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

and my fragment_list.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@android:id/list" />

    <TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:text="No data"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

When i will give input in edittext box and call place api and then parse json data. I have written Place class and then add place object in list. so please someone tell me that how to display empty text. app is showing exception in arrayadapter.getCount() method.

Comment: getListView().setEmptyView(emptyTextView );

Answer (score 0):

Your `placeList` is never initialized.

Moreover, in `onCreateView()`, you should probably create your `view` like this:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
```